# Pattern overlay on GDI+ text

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing, gdi+

I;m drawing text onto a Graphics object width GDI+. Is it possible to overlay a pattern, or texture ontop of this text? I'm hoping to create an effect similar to a photoshop pattern overlay.

Comment: Any screen shot to depict what effect you want?

Comment: Graphics.DrawString() takes a brush, use a TextureBrush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own brush for filling text. To get the effect of 'overlaying a pattern' just define a brush with the pattern you want. Example for a linear gradient fill is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984365(v=vs.71).aspx